# Creating a New control of the same type as another control that is already declared

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, winforms, controls

I'm using a custom template class to generate lines with my repeater control, i'd like to be able to specify the controls in this repeater dynamically from the code behind my aspx page.
In the code behind I've added controls to a list like this:

```
Dim lstControls As New List(Of Control)
lstControls.Add(New TextBox)
lstControls.Add(New Label)
lstControls.Add(New CheckBox)
lstControls.Add(New DropDownList)
lstControls.Add(New CheckBox)
```

Then i use this line to add the controls to my template

```
rptrSummary.ItemTemplate = New myTemplate(ListItemType.Item, , lstControls)
```

From the instantiateIn sub i'm doing something like this:

```
Dim ph As New PlaceHolder

For i = 0 To lstControls.Count - 1
    ph.Controls.Add(lstControls(i))
Next
```

This doesn't work properly and following .databind() of my repeater control the controls i specify only appear on the final row. I think this is because i've only declared the controls as NEW once, so i only have one rows worth.

***tldr?/ conclusion:***

How can i generate new controls of the same type as controls from my list? Something like:

```
Dim newControl as new Control = type(lstControl(0))
```

(this obviously doesn't work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer, here are some examples in case anyone else is stuck (i may also change the title so it's more similar to likely search criteria):

```
dim egTextbox as new textbox
dim egLabel as new label

dim newObject1 as Object = Activator.CreateInstance(egTextbox.GetType)
dim newObject2 as Object = Activator.CreateInstance(egLabel.GetType)
```

newObject1 is now a textbox
newObject2 is now a label