# Convert a String to Call a Public Class ASP.NET VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have looked at this link and I cannot seem to get it to work

[Creating a New control of the same type as another control that is already declared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13931050/creating-a-new-control-of-the-same-type-as-another-control-that-is-already-decla)

I have also tried this from searches:

```
Dim ClassToCreate As String = "TestClass1.CountItems"

Dim myInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(ClassToCreate), True)
```

Error is:

```
"Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: type"
```

Problem:
I have multiple classes and want to change which one is called based on a string.
(example is not correct of course)

```
Dim strClassToCall = "TestClass1.CountItems"
```

'then convert the string to the actual class so it can be called like this:

```
Dim strResult = TestClass1.CountItems(strSomeParameter)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I would advice against using reflection...Why not make all classes implement an interface, so you can call the interface's method instead of trying to mess around with reflection?

Comment: Thanks Andrei, just to confirm, this interface would be a class of its own that would then call the class from a CASE or ELSEIF type of thing??

Comment: You wouldn't need a Case or If statement. Since all of your classes would implement the method in your interface, you can just call it. Say you have an interface called `ICommunicate`(interfaces usually start with an I). This interface only has one method: `Talk()`. You then create a class `Dog` and class `Person` that implement this interface. Since both of them implement `ICommunicate` you can just call the Talk() method on any of them. (You can receive as a parameter of a function an `ICommunicate` object, instead of a `Person` or `Dog`, so you can call `Talk()` independently of the class)

Comment: Based on your example, TestClass1.CountItems seems to be a function, not a class.

Comment: Type.GetType(ClassName) and classType.InvokeMember

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message it sounds like your `Type` is not getting loaded properly as it is null.  The method you are using will create the object like you need assuming you get the valid `Type` to pass to the activator.  Is the type coming from an referenced DLL?

Here is one method you could use to get the type if just using the string representation is not working.  This uses reflection to find the type:

```
// Sorry this is c# :)
System.Reflection.Assembly pAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(
    System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().
    GetReferencedAssemblies().Single(a => a.Name.Equals("YourNamespace.ClassName")));
yourType = pAssembly.GetTypes().First(c => (c.FullName != null) &&
    c.FullName.Equals("YourNamespace.ClassName"));
var yourObject = Activator.CreateInstance(yourType, true);
```

Comment: Thanks Kelsy, I am going to start with Andrei's point first (sorry) but I am going to test yours too

Comment: @JTT2 an interface is definitely the way to go if you are not dealing with complicated scenarios where you have more different types of objects that you are trying to utilize.  I figured that would have been the first approach that led you to need to go this route as it is much more complex :)

Comment: I am actually trying to use

Comment: Type.GetType(ClassName) and classType.InvokeMember

Comment: unsuccessfully though so I am going to start a new question for that